# Autocompleting textbox from jquery combobox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, combobox

I have been following an online tutorial to autocomplete textboxes with database values after the user enters a code greater than 7 characters. I have completed most of what I am trying to achieve however I cannot seem to select a value from the combobox to autocomplete the textbox.
I dont have much javascript experience but I am hoping the problem is something small in what I already have, can someone please recommend the change I need to make to select the value from the combobox.

```
public ActionResult MultiColumnComboBox(string SearchFor, string ControlId)
    {
        ViewBag.ProcId = SearchFor.Trim();
        ViewBag.ControlBlockId = "block" + ControlId.Trim();
        ViewBag.ControlId = ControlId.Trim();
        ViewBag.ControlTxtId = "txt" + ControlId.Trim();

        return View();
    }

    public JsonResult LoadComboData(string strSearch, string SearchFor)
    {
        efacsdbEntities db = new efacsdbEntities();
        strSearch = strSearch.Trim();
        if (SearchFor.Trim() == "employee" && strSearch.Length>7)
        {
            var res = (from E in db.allpartmasters
                       where E.partnum.ToLower().Contains(strSearch.ToLower()) || E.partdesc.ToLower().Contains(strSearch.ToLower())
                       select new
                       {
                           E.partnum,
                           E.partdesc
                       }).ToList();
            return Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

```js
<input type="hidden" id="@ViewBag.ProcId" name="@ViewBag.ProcId" value="" />
<input type="hidden" id="@ViewBag.ControlId" name="@ViewBag.ControlId" value="" />
<input type="text" name="@ViewBag.ControlTxtId" id="@ViewBag.ControlTxtId" autocomplete="on" />
<div class="@ViewBag.ControlTxtId renderpart">
    <div class="DataBlock">
        <div id="@ViewBag.ControlBlockId" style="max-width: 520px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/json.debug.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".renderpart").hide();
        var txtid = "#" + '@ViewBag.ControlTxtId';
        var renderpart = "." + '@ViewBag.ControlTxtId';
        var selectlinkvalueid = ".Get" + '@ViewBag.ProcId';

        $(selectlinkvalueid).on("click", function () {
            var value = $(this).attr('id');
            var valueText = $(this).attr('title');
            $("#@ViewBag.ControlId").val(value);
            $(txtid).val(valueText);
            $(renderpart).slideUp("slow");
        });

        $(txtid).keyup(function () {
            var value = $(txtid).val();
            var Procvalue = '@ViewBag.ProcId';
            var controlid = "#" + '@ViewBag.ControlBlockId';

            value = encodeURI(value);
            if (value.length > 2) {
                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
                $.getJSON("/Test/LoadComboData", { strSearch: " " + value, SearchFor: " " + Procvalue }, function (data) {
                    $(controlid).html("");
                    var activecols = $("#hdnActiveColumns").val();
                    var htmlrow = "";
                    var tempprocId = '@ViewBag.ProcId';
                    var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);
                    $(controlid).html(CreateDynamicTable(jsondata, tempprocId));
                    $(renderpart).slideDown("slow");
                });
                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
            }
            else {
                $(renderpart).slideUp("slow");
            }
        });
        $(txtid).focusin(function () {
            var txtid = "#" + '@ViewBag.ControlTxtId';
            var value = $(txtid).val();
            var Procvalue = '@ViewBag.ProcId';
            var controlid = "#" + '@ViewBag.ControlBlockId';
            value = encodeURI(value);
            if (value.length > 2) {
                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
                $.getJSON("/Test/LoadComboData", { strSearch: " " + value, SearchFor: " " + Procvalue }, function (data) {
                    $(controlid).html("");
                    var htmlrow = "";
                    var tempprocId = '@ViewBag.ProcId';
                    var jsondata = JSON.stringify(data);
                    $(controlid).html(CreateDynamicTable(jsondata, tempprocId));
                    $(renderpart).slideDown("slow");
                });
                $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
            }
            else {
                $(renderpart).slideUp("slow");
            }
        });
        function CreateDynamicTable(objArray, tempprocId) {
            var array = JSON.parse(objArray);
            var str = '<table style="width:100%;">';
            str += '<tr>';
            for (var index in array[0]) {
                str += '<th scope="col">' + index + '</th>';
            }
            str += '</tr>';
            str += '<tbody>';
            var flag = false;
            var ids;
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                str += (i % 2 == 0) ? '<tr>' : '<tr>';
                for (var index in array[i]) {
                    if (flag == false) {
                        ids = array[i][index];
                        flag = true;
                    }
                    str += '<td><a id="' + ids + '" class="Get' + tempprocId + '" title="' + array[i][index] + '" href="#">' + array[i][index] + '</a></td>';
                }
                str += '</tr>';
            }
            str += '</tbody>';
            str += '</table>';
            return str;
        }
    });
    $(document).click(function (evt) {
        var renderpart = "." + '@ViewBag.ControlTxtId';
        var theElem = (evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : evt.target;

        if (theElem.id == "main" || theElem.id == "sub1") {
            $(renderpart).slideUp("fast");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here is the link to the tutorial I was following as well.

[Create Multiple column autocomplete combobox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/487501/Create-Multiple-Column-Autocomplete-Combobox-in-AS?fid=1810718)

Comment: Use jQuery UI auto-complete, instead of trying to create the auto-complete textbox from scratch. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: I had looked at this but had problems trying to install the plugin, is there no other way?

Comment: The best autocomplete jquery plugin is [select2](https://select2.github.io/). Docs are really good.

Comment: @cg91, then post a new question asking about the problem you had when installing the plugin.